# Modifying the text resolution of the Iphone

Tags: iphone

not the image resolultion but the text resolution of on Iphone, how to do that?
@2x change the image resolution but what about the text? Got  to be a way to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

They do this automatically. If you set `font-size: 16px` it's going to act as `font-size: 32px` on an iPhone 4. Nothing you need to do on your end.